# counting how many times unique value occur in column with reference to other column in .csv using python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, csv, bioinformatics

I want to calculate for each unique "extId" how many different "Annotation.exact" are occuring, i have attached an image for the reference, i have a file of about 10 million rows so i can't do manually, so i am using python for that, i am using below code for that but i'm not getting the "extdId" with new sheet only getting the count values, please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv('master file.csv')
#master_df = pd.DataFrame()
df.head()
print(df['extId'].value_counts())

master_df=df['extId'].value_counts()
master_df.to_csv('id_count.csv', index=False)
```

[image]

expected output, which should be in two column, one should be "extId" and the other should be "count".

[image]

Comment: check out "[ask]" as well how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @ashleedawg let me know if you have better suggestion.

Comment: If you add  **expected output** in your question, it will be easier for someone to help you. Are you limited to python solutions only?

Comment: @c_bfx nice suggestion, yeah 'm implementing this whole thing on python.

Comment: if you add sample input in the text file format instead of image, one can test their solutions. can you please try this `master_df=df.value_counts(['extId'])` instead of this `master_df=df['extId'].value_counts()`

Comment: @c_bfx can we connect somewhere else? discord?